# "Loading kernel" останавливает загрузку Debian

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-mint

После долгих попыток, *Linux Betsy2* наконец установился на SSD моего ноутбука. Однако при перезагрузке компьютера система пишет `Loading kernel` и дальше не загружается. Возможные причины я вижу такие:

1. В файле fstab.

   ```
   UNCONFIGURED FSTAB FOR BASE SYSTEM

   aufs / aufs rw 0 0
   tmpfs /tmp tmpfs nosuid, nodev 0 0
   ```

   В файл были добавлены строчки:

   ```
   LABEL=root / ext4 defaults 0 1
   LABEL=home /home ext4 defaults 0 2
   LABEL=swap none swap sw 0 0
   ```

   Но это не очень помогло.
2. Не загрузились драйвера для видеокарты. Думала, что это можно сделать после установки. (Система установилась без них).
3. Не загрузила пакеты обновлений, как того требовала установка. Но система установилась без них, все таки это свежая версия дистрибутива.

Пожалуйста, помогите идеей или ссылкой. Все советы из интернета уже перепробовала!

Comment: Если загрузчик (какой?) повисает на загрузке кернела, то fstab тут точно непричём - до него, ещё как до Турции пешком.

Основная гипотеза - либо загрузчик не видит файл с образом кернела (неправильно задано имя файла), либо образа кернела просто нет на диске !.

Comment: Сергей, большое спасибо! Еще немного помучилась и решила проблему. Нужно было обновить grub, похоже, конфликт версий какой-то.

Comment: @Sergey, бывают и более интересные сюрпризы, но в большинстве случаев ваша гипотеза справедлива.